# React Redux: Isn't shouldComponentUpdate similiar to Angular watchers

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redux, flux

React in its Advance performance sections talks about about shouldComponentUpdate function.

It allows us to prevent component render when return false.

With redux where container components subscribe for a store update, we generally define shouldComponentUpdate to avoid rerender if not required.

So my query isn't it the same thing what angular watchers does automatically. Digest cycle goes through all watchers and compare the expressions.

Comment: I don't agree that it's the same, and I can possibly write a few lines about why. But even if it is the same, why are you asking? If they are similar, does that lead you to some other conclusion?

Comment: In case they are same then multiple watchers were responsible for slowing down an angular application. Will using multiple shoulComponentUpdate have any performance impact.

Comment: Well it doesn't work the same in react, I suggest you read about what causes rendering in react and about components lifecycle, and you will get a better understanding about why it's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Redux (or any flux-like implementation), the two are definitely not equal.

First of all, the $digest loop is applied for two-way data binding, while in React this is generally frowned upon. Instead, generally a unidirectional data flow is promoted also known as the flux paradigm (Redux, for the most part, follows this paradigm).

Secondly, when you are using Redux, your state changes in the store become *immutable*. Because of that, no "dirty checking" is necessary for the values, because whenever a value changes the "whole" value changes (its reference). Therefore, React only has to compare by reference and does not have to actually compare whatever that reference points to.

Also, when using Redux with [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), you probably won't have to implement shouldComponentUpdate at all. react-redux does this reference checking for you using a "shallow compare" (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html). If you're finding you still get unnecessary re-renders, it probably has to do with mutations being made to the state when mapping state to props. To solve this, you could use something like [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.